# Registering Hive Custom UDF with Spark (Spark SQL) 2.0.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I am working on a spark 2.0.0 piece where my requirement is to use 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows' function in my sql context to use in one of the queries. In my cluster with Hive query, I use this as a temporary function just by defining : CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myFunc AS 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows', which is quite simple.

I tried registering this with sparkSession as below but got an error:

```
sparkSession.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myFunc AS 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows'""")
```

Error :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION rowsequence AS 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows'
16/11/01 20:46:17 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Use sqlContext.udf.register(...) instead.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Use sqlContext.udf.register(...) instead.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.makeFunctionBuilder(SessionCatalog.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateFunctionCommand.run(functions.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)
    at com.mediamath.spark.attribution.sparkjob.SparkVideoCidJoin$.delayedEndpoint$com$mediamath$spark$attribution$sparkjob$SparkVideoCidJoin$1(SparkVideoCidJoin.scala:75)
    at com.mediamath.spark.attribution.sparkjob.SparkVideoCidJoin$delayedInit$body.apply(SparkVideoCidJoin.scala:22)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.mediamath.spark.attribution.sparkjob.SparkVideoCidJoin$.main(SparkVideoCidJoin.scala:22)
    at com.mediamath.spark.attribution.sparkjob.SparkVideoCidJoin.main(SparkVideoCidJoin.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
```

Does anybody have idea how to register it as spark is asking, i.e. with register api in sparkSession and SQLContext:

```
 sqlContext.udf.register(...)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Spark 2.0,

```
sparkSession.udf.register(...)
```

allows you to register Java or Scala UDFs (functions of type Long => Long), but not Hive [GenericUDFs](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFCeil.java) that handle LongWritable instead of Long, and that can have a variable number of arguments.

To register Hive UDFs, your first approach was correct:

```
sparkSession.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myFunc AS 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows'""")
```

However you must enable Hive support first:

```
SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport()
```

and make sure that the "spark-hive" dependencies are present in your classpath.

Explanation:

Your error message

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Use sqlContext.udf.register(...) instead
```

comes from the class [SessionCatalog](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/catalog/SessionCatalog.scala).

By calling [SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L774), spark
will replace the SessionCatalog with a HiveSessionCatalog in which the method [makeFunctionBuilder](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveSessionCatalog.scala#L111) is implemented.

Lastly:

the UDF you want to use, 'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows', has been written in a time where Windowing Functions were not available in Hive.
I suggest you to use them instead. You can check the [Hive Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics),
this [Spark-SQL intro](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html), or [this if you want to stick to the scala syntax](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-windows.html).

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to this question - it should be just a comment

Comment: @T.Gawęda thank you for pointing out my answer wasn't clear enough. I took the time to rewrite it more clearly.

Comment: @FurryMachine thank you. Can I use `sparkSession.udf.register()` to register UDF from JAR files?

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing it's that Spark is not loading the jar library in his classPath.

In our team we are loading external libraries with --jars option.

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit  --jars external_library.jar our_program.py --our_params
```

You can check if you are loading external libraries in **Spark History - Environment** Tab. (*spark.yarn.secondary.jars*)

Then you will be able to register your **udf** as you said. Once you enable HiveSupport as FurryMachine says.

```
sparkSession.sql("""
    CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION myFunc AS  
    'com.facebook.hive.udf.UDFNumberRows'
""")
```

You can found more info in **spark-summit --help**

```
hadoop:~/projects/neocortex/src$ spark-submit --help
Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]   
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]

Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn, or local.
  --deploy-mode DEPLOY_MODE   Whether to launch the driver program locally ("client") or
                              on one of the worker machines inside the cluster ("cluster")
                              (Default: client).
  --class CLASS_NAME          Your application's main class (for Java / Scala apps).
  --name NAME                 A name of your application.
  --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register a UDF directly using `SparkSession` as in `sparkSession.udf.register("myUDF", (arg1: Int, arg2: String) => arg2 + arg1)`. Look at the detailed documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession)